# A question about polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_0$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and whose degree is at least $2$. Suppose each $a_i \ (0\leq i \leq n-1)$ is of the form $a_i=\pm \frac{17!}{r!(17-r)!}$ with $1\leq r \leq 16$. Show that $f(m)$ is not equal to zero for any integer $m$.

My approach : Is it something to do with the irreducibility of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? If so, how to show this?

Comment: Start by thinking about the LCM of the denominators of $a_i$.

Comment: Well, each $a_i$ eventually becomes a multiple of $17$ for all $1\leq r\leq 16$.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't want $a_r = \pm \frac{17!}{r!(17-r)!} = \pm \binom{17} r$, in which case this is a particularly nice binomial expansion and I suspect the result is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Every $a_i$ is a multiple of $17$, so if $f(b)=0$, with $b$ integer, we must have $17\mid b$. Thus $b=17c$; hence
$$
0=17^nc^n+17^na_{n-1}'c^{n-1}+17^{n-1}a_{n-2}'c^{n-2}+\dots+17^2a_1'c+17a_0' \tag{*}
$$
where
$$
a_i'=\frac{a_i}{17}
$$
Divide (*) by $17$:
$$
0=17^{n-1}c^n+17^{n-1}a_{n-1}'c^{n-1}+17^{n-2}a_{n-2}'c^{n-2}+\dots+17a_1'c+a_0'
$$
Can you see the contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

$\binom {17}{r}$ is divisible by $17$  but not by $17^2$ for $1\leq r \leq 16$ because $17$ is prime. So $f(x)$ satisfies Eisenstein's Criterion. So $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x].$

BTW $f(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in \mathbb Q$ by a theorem  of Gauss: If $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x].$

Comment: Actually $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Eisenstein's criterion as you showed, and since $f$ is a primitive polynomial here (why?) and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}$, so by Gauss' lemma we conclude $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Yes. I had it the wrong way around.